# How to check multiple urls about their status code in R

Tags: r, url, rstudio

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/get")
status_code(r)

data$URLS
#Where data$URLS is a column of URLS

data$status <- GET(data$URLS)
status_code(data$URLS)
```

Comment: You may use a loop `for(i in seq_along(data$URLS)) {tmp <- GET(data$URLS[i]); print(status_code(tmp))}`

Answer (score 1):

We could use a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(urls)) {
    tmp <- GET(urls[i])
    print(status_code(tmp))
}
#[1] 200
#[1] 200
```

#### data

```
urls <-c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA")
```